# Iterate over images in Document Library in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, document-library

I want to display images which are present in the liferay Document Library.
How should I iterate to get all the images and display them?

The code that I have right now is :

```jsp
<portlet:renderURL  var="viewImageDataURL"/>

<liferay-ui:search-container delta="20" emptyResultsMessage="No Results Found">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
            total="<%= employeeImages.size() %>"
            results="<%= ListUtil.subList(employeeImages, searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" />
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="search"
            className="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil">

        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                name="ImageName"
                value = '<img  src="<%=search.getDLFileEntry(1)%>"/>'>
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator searchContainer="<%=searchContainer %>" paginate="<%=true%>" />

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

How should I iterate? The function to diplay images from Document Library is `getDLFileEntry(fileId)`, I want to display all the values.

**Edited Code:**

The code I used is:

```jsp
<portlet:renderURL  var="viewImageDataURL"/>

<liferay-ui:search-container delta="20" emptyResultsMessage="No Results Found">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        total="<%=DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getDLFileEntriesCount() %>"
        results="<%=DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntries(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd())%>" />

    <liferay-ui:search-container-row
            modelVar="search"
            className="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileEntry">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                name="ImageName"
                value = '<img src="<%=search.getDLFileEntries(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd())%>"/>'>
        </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator searchContainer="<%=searchContainer %>" paginate="<%=true%>" />

</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

The error is shown in the line below:

and the error description is:

> com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileEntry cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value className  , you provided for  seems incorrect.

I believe results value would be list of type DLFileEntry in your case.

Here you could have specified className as Model name [com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileEntry] you want to iterate in Search Container.
keyProperty as some primary-key name for model,

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-row className="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileEntry" keyProperty="fileEntryId" modelVar="searchRow">
```

Now, searchRow can be treated as object of iteration.

You can call any getter method of model DLFileEntry to use it for display.

===============================================================================
`<liferay-ui:search-container searchContainer="${searchContainerObj}">
                    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="<%=LIST OF OBJECT OF DLFileEntry%>"/>
                        <liferay-ui:search-container-row className="com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileEntry" keyProperty="fileEntryId" modelVar="fileEntry">
                                <img src="<%= DLUtil.getThumbnailSrc(fileEntry, fileEntry.getFileVersion(), null, themeDisplay) %>" />
                        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

</liferay-ui:search-container>`

Let me explain terminology of above code.
liferay-ui:search-container-results tag will have list of object, you want to show in search-container.
liferay-ui:search-container-row tag will define modelVar fileEntry, which will be iteration object of type of List objects.
In body of liferay-ui:search-container-row , modelVar fileEntry will be available.
**Here if results List is of size 3 then 3 thumbnail images will be shown.**

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for such a prompt reply and a nice explanation. I understood what you are saying about className. But could You explain with an example about resultrow, searchRow and results?

Comment: I have edited my code but it doesn't work
I have pasted it above in my question itself under EDITEDCODE

Comment: Well Seeya, here search is object of type DLFileEntry. Also you cant use `<img/>` tag as a value of `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>`. In `<liferay-ui:search-container-row>` tag body , search object is available and you can utilize it to get any information. Also you can have other html syntax in`<liferay-ui:search-container-row>` tag.

Comment: Pankaj can you give me an example of how to use it? I am getting confused with it.. And how should I use getFileEntry(long imageid) function to pass id of every image?

Comment: I am still getting the same error that com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileEntry cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Pankaj in your above code, <%=LIST OF OBJECT OF DLFileEntry%> how do I implement it? I mean how should I call the objects?? Sorry for sounding dumb but I am very new to liferay and using it for my internship project..

Comment: its the same `DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileEntries(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd())`

Comment: Ya thanks for that but now the error that I get is in the following line:
<img src="<%=DLUtil.getThumbnailSrc(fileEntry, fileEntry.getVersion(), null, themeDisplay) %>" />

The error is :

The method getThumbnailSrc(FileEntry, FileVersion, DLFileShortcut, ThemeDisplay) in the 
  type DLUtil is not applicable for the arguments (DLFileEntry, String, null, ThemeDisplay)

Comment: I still get the error that com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.impl.DLFileEntry cannot be resolved to a type 

I have it imported in my file. What is the cause of the problem?